# Excel contains filter with more than 2 values

Tags: excel, vba, macos, excel-formula

Does anyone know how I can quickly hide/remove all rows in sheet1 that contain any of the rows info from sheet2?

It would need to contains filter as it wouldn't be an *exact* match.

For example

**Sheet1:**

```
http://www.google.com/something/else
http://www.yahoo.com/whatever
www.microsoft.com/hahha
```

**Sheet2:**

```
google.com
```

So the end result would be the first line in Sheet1 would be hidden

In practice I'm working with thousands of rows in sheet1 and around in Sheet2.

To clarify, I'm essentially trying to do a contains filter with more than 2 values - the default filter only allows 2 values.

Also I am working with Excel for Mac 2011.

Comment: what are sheets names and which columns is your data using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this quickly with a simple helper column without a large range loop.

For simplicity as a sample:

- Assuming your Sheet 1 list was in `A1:A1000`
- your Sheet 2 partial list was in `C1:C5` (on the same sheet for the picture below)
- then in range `B1:B1000` enter this array formula, 
  `=MAX(IF(ISERROR(FIND($C$1:$C$5,A1)),0,1))=1`

*(Enter as an array formula by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)*

- Then AutoFilter the `TRUE`rows (which flag any matches) and hide them

[image]

Comment: For some reason all of them return true for me and it says Formula refers to empty cells. I have it setup the same way you do with this formula.

=MAX(IF(ISERROR(FIND($C$1:$C$579,A1)),0,1))=1 and I made sure to hold command + shift + enter so it's an array formula. (it shows curly brackets).

This is one a Mac Excel, so would that make a difference?

Comment: New information :) I don't have experience with Mac Excel - I wouldn't have thought it would make a difference, especially if your array seems to have worked (command key or ctrl key?), but I'll pass this by a Mac expert.

Comment: And when the formula copies down, the A row does increment beyond row 1 ?ie `B2 = =MAX(IF(ISERROR(FIND($C$1:$C$5,A2)),0,1))=1` etc

Comment: Sorry I thought I had included Mac for Excel in the OP.  I changed it accordingly now.  Yes, the A row does increment by one but they all say referencing empty cell for some reason when I see the data right in the next column.  I'm going to try this on Excel on my PC and see if that works.

Comment: @Zen: Ok I tested in both Win/Mac Excel. The above formula works on both... PROVIDED if you have mentioned `$C$1:$C$5` then ensure that there are no blank cells say in cell C4:C5 else you will get undesired results.

Answer (score 2):

As i was reading the solution posted by @brettdj I think it should work for your problem.

From your comment it seems you have an empty cell problem when using his solution. Are you sure you replaced the `$C$1 : $c$5` with the right values?

In your case you should first refer to the right sheet (`Sheet2` if you didn't rename it) then the right column (assuming you have it in column A of sheet2).

You should write `=MAX(IF(ISERROR(FIND(sheet2!$A$1:$A$5,sheet1!A1)),0,1))=1`.

Comment: Ahh just found a problem.  I did indeed have an empty cell hidden in the middle of those 700 or so cells. Once I removed those, it worked like a charm!

Comment: + 1 Yup That was the issue. Sorry had not seen your post :)